# From a Poisson algebra to its geometric dual

Tags: representation-theory, spectral-theory, duality-theorems, poisson-geometry, gelfand-representation

I am trying to recover a Poisson manifold from its algebraic (commutative) dual. So I looked at the side of Gelfand transformation (since a Poisson algebra is a commutative Banach algebra). Gelfand transformation states exactly this:

$A \to C(Spec(A)), a \mapsto (h \to h (a))$

My question is how to precisely determine $h$. We should normally find the characters of A (by Casimir functions ?). But after ? I can not conclude.

Thanks for your help

Nicolas